# terraform validate to check only for syntax and not rest things

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

currently I am running below shell command

```
@if [ -x "$$(command -v terraform)" ]; then \
    echo "==> Checking terraform formatting of files"; \
    (terraform validate ./test && echo "Terraform format check passed successfully") \
    || (echo "validation failed" && exit 1); \
else \
    echo "No terraform command found"; \
    exit 1; \
fi
```

here I dont want to initialize the backend but it seems it does that and I also see error as

```
?   on test/policy.tf line 320:
?  320: module "service_admin_policy" {
?
? This module is not yet installed. Run "terraform init" to install all
? modules required by this configuration.

terraform version = 1.1.6
```

using terraform validate I just want to check if the .tf files in a directory are just syntactically correct like braces missing and comma kind of stuff.
any help on how I can ignore these errors.

Comment: "Reference to undeclared input variable" - you forgot to post your TF code that generates the error.

Comment: @Marcin sorry that was a wrong ask, updated the question

Comment: It can't validate the code unless you run `terraform init` to download the modules/providers first.

Comment: @MarkoE what does the option terraform init -backend=false does ? If I use that will it be helpful? I don't want to break anything on the remote state

Comment: Also I see `terraform validate -check-variables=false` gives error like `? Error: Failed to parse command-line flags
?
? flag provided but not defined: -check-variables`

Comment: @Jenifer the `-check-variables` flag was removed in Terraform 0.12 (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21408#issuecomment-495259124)

Answer (score 5):

Validate works at the level of checking your code for soundness, including loading modules and ensuring that variables are correctly named.

If you only want basic syntax of a local file, consider using `terraform fmt -write=false`. If the formatter is unable to parse the file, it will throw an error.

Comment: The only drawback of `terraform fmt` is that it also checks format and style like indentations, line breaks and so on.

Comment: @Sebastian You might think that from other linting tools, but it's not the case. If you run `terraform fmt -write=false` on syntactically correct code, it will print a list of all files with linting errors to stdout and exit successfully. If you run it on syntactically incorrect code, it will exit with a failure code and print an error to stderr.

Comment: @DanMonego Thanks for this, as far as reading documents I understood that terraform validate cannot be applied generically for the syntax.
but with terraform fmt -write false and terraform fmt -check what is the major difference ? if my use case is only checking syntax ? and also do I need to do terraform init in order to run terraform fmt

Comment: Running it with `-write=false` will succeed on valid code with improper formatting, and only fail on syntactically invalid code. Running it with `-check` will fail if any formatting errors exist - things like indentation or strange brace placement. `terraform fmt` does not require `terraform init` to be run.